# Overwrite if newer : SCP folder transfer

Tags: ssh, scp

WinSCP has a great feature that only copies newer versions of files when you transfer between hosts.  For whatever reason, I'm not able to connect to my remote host via WinSCP so I must use SSH.  I don't want to overwrite ever file in the target folder, only the new ones. Does this happen automatically?

Additionally, for the protocol: `scp -r [/path/filename][login@ipaddress]:.` what is the **home** directory of the filename path? Is it simply `C` drive? I know I can write the full path but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a lot of misguided thoughts here.

First... Winscp uses native ssh to copy files.  It does nothing different than the linux command `scp`.  There is no way scp will work... when winscp does not.  winscp is a windows interface that uses a basic scp client to connect to a ssh server to copy files.

Second... In Linux-based OSes, there is no concept of a "C drive".  You have the root (/) and directories under root.  A block device is mounted to root, and various other block devices can be mounted to directories that fall under root.

The syntax for "scp" is as follows:

```
scp from_where to_where
```

Both the from and to can be local directories like `/some/local/directory` or a remote directory like `user@some.server:/some/remote/directory`

the `-r` just means to "recurse" directories. (copy everything from that directory and everything beneath it.)

in a windows environment with a "C drive"  typically you'd use putty's pscp command and do something like this:

```
pscp -r c:\some\directory username@some.server:/some/path/to/where/you/want/it
```

Comment: This is all great but in answering the original question: Is overwrite if new a default for scp?

Comment: Since scp is rather simple... (doesn't do much beyond copying) It doesn't have any way to determine if there are newer files on the remote side.  Your best bet is to look at rsync or unison over ssh or use some enhanced scp/sftp client like winscp.

Comment: I prefer `scp FromHere ToThere`

Comment: @AmitNaidu alas... Windows does not have a native scp client.  You can use putty's pscp... or cygwin's scp... or some other 3rd party scp client... but I find putty is crazy-small and extremely powerful/efficient.

Answer (score 3):

If your priority is to overwrite with newer copies, I recommend rsync.

cwRsync is a version you can use with Windows: http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html